# Export user input from c# form to excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Ok so maybe this is a stupid question, but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere(possibly because I'm not wording it right)

I have this (really)simple app that I had to make for a project.

basically, the user puts info into the windows form which I then want exported to excel.

here's the part I'm struggling with,

One of the fields is groceries(it's a sort of budgetting app)
I want to be able to add groceries for a few times a month, like maybe once a week or so and then have that exported to excel spreadsheet that can be viewed by the user. 
At the end of the month, it will take that final amount and subtract it from a salary that is put in.

So the question is, how do I, after each time I add groceries, save it in excel and save the next input in the same field without overwriting the first one?

eg.
groceries $40, then next week groceries $20, and the following week $15.
In the end all of the above will have been entered into the same textbox on different occassions and in excel I want to be able to see all 3 amounts. From there I can see that the total spent on groceries for the month is $75.

I hope that makes sense,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code to post? "save the next input in the same field without over writing" do you want to add it to existing value?

Comment: @Scubacode: Is the question "How do I export data to an Excel file"?

Comment: Not really. I'm pretty sure on how to take a single value from lets say textbox1 and put it into cell A1. The question is really how do I, take a second value from textbox1 and put it into A2, and a third to A3, and so forth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export to excel, I would either do it by writing a simple semicolon separated file (.csv), or if you need a proper Excel file, I would use the very easy to use third party library EPPlus, which you can find here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Comment: I copied a method I have, that creates an excel file from some database data, to pastebin. Have a look at it, and see if it helps. http://pastebin.com/15rGExKU